# Codeigniter comparison input with database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to comparise string from input to string in database.
This is my code:

Controller:

```
public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();  
        $this->captcha_rejestracja = rand(1,40);

    }
    public function register() {

    $str = $this->input->post('captcharejestr');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcharejestr', 'kod z obrazka', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|callback_captcha_check[$str]');

    }
    public function captcha_check($str) {

            $jakacaptcha = $this->captcha_rejestracja;
            $this->load->model('Tresci');

            if ($str != $this->Tresci->captcha($jakacaptcha))
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check', 'Błędnie przepisany kod z obrazka.');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                return TRUE;
            }

        }
```

Model:

```
public function captcha($jakacaptcha) {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT kod FROM captcha WHERE numer='.$jakacaptcha.'');

        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row['kod'];

    }
```

I dont know where is the problem because everytime i have return FALSE from my callback ??

Answer (score 0):

### You don't seem to be running the form validation.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
            
    // this is somewhat confusing, why randon value ?
    // the database query should have one value :-/
    $this->captcha_rejestracja = rand(1,40);
            
    $this->load->model('Tresci');
            
}
```

---

```
public function register()
{
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'label', 'callback_captcha_check' );
        
     if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
         //show the form again
         return;
     }
        
     //create a new user
 }
```

---

```
 public function captcha_check($str)
 {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check', 'Message here...');
        
     $result = $this->tresci->captcha($this->captcha_rejestracja);
        
     return ( $str == (string)$result ) ? true : false;
 }
```

Comment: thx for your time but i find my problem. With script everything was ok. But i had problem with comparise captcha send before and captcha what is actually on the screen. $this->input->post($str); .. and everything its ok!! thanks for your time